# Set alert in central administration to notify when timer job fails?

Tags: user-profile-service, central-administration, alert, timer-jobs

Is there a way to set an alert in SharePoint 2010 Central Administration to notify an administrator when a timer job fails? For example, I'd like to be notified when the following job's status equals `Failed`:

[image: Failed timer job]

We've been having trouble with our User Profile Service application failing to do an incremental synchronization, but don't have a mechanism in place to alert an administrator when the job fails. This means that we're only noticing when this job fails when someone goes to manually check on how things are running. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no OOTB way to setup alerts on the timer job.

- You can use the 3rd party tools which is best way, to montior the sharepoint farm. We are using the SCOM from MSFT.
- Other way is write some piece of code which parse the Server Application log and report when an event related to failure occur.
- Or write a powershell script and schedule it as per your need, which will notify about the job status, running, failed or successful.